# Import an entire geopackage into PostGIS via DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, geopackage, dbmanager

I am trying to important an entire geopackage to a PostGIS database via the Import Layer/File button in DB Manager. However when I do this only one of the layers in the geopackage gets successfully imported. Do I have to import each layer individually or there a way I can import the entire geopackage at once? It would be ideal if I could do this in DB Manager as QGIS is the software I am most familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import option in the DB Manager is made to work for one layer at a time. I would do the job with ogr2ogr. If the GPKG layers are not listed in the command, or defined by the `-sql` option, then all layers are converted.

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"<connection parameters>" input.gpkg
```

Comment: I am guessing you enter that code in the SQL window of DB Manager?

Comment: No. The command is entered into a command shell. Naturally you must have GDAL command line tools installed.